# nodejs, jquery ajax, the format conversion of the transfer and receiving objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

for example 
the ajax to send a obj to node js router '/test'

```
var obj =new object();
obj.a='a';
obj.b='b';

$.ajax({
    url:"/test",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
      obj:obj
    },success:function(){


    },error:function(){

    }
});
```

the '/test' router receiving obj:

```
router.post('/test',function(req, res, next){

    for(var key in req.body){
        console.log(key);
        console.log(req.body[key]);
    }
    res.end();
});
```

This object is automatically convert to a different format

```
{
'obj[a]':'a',
'obj[b]':'b'
}
```

the key is not `'a'`, is convert to `'obj[a]'`

How can I receive or send correctly?

like this:

the `console.log(req.body.obj);` is:

```
{
  a:a,
  b:b
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to pass `data: obj` to `$.ajax()`, not `data: {obj: obj}`.  You are the one nesting it in another object that you don't want.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/test",
    type:"POST",
    data:obj,
    success:function(){

    }, error:function(){

    }
});
```

Also, note that you will need some middleware to properly parse this back into JSON on your server.  Otherwise, it will just be a string.

Comment: What if there are n objects? obj_1,obj_2...obj_n

Comment: @AlbertChen - The `$.ajax()` doc says that the `data` property you pass has to be a single object of key/value pairs because it is going to serialize it in url query form of `aaa=xxx&bbb=yyy` or a string or an array.  If you want a more complicated data structure, then just serialize it yourself with `JSON.stringify()` and then `JSON.parse()` it on the other end.  For multiple objects, you could pass an array of objects or you can use `JSON.stringify()` first and pass a string and then use `JSON.parse()` on the server to get back the array.

Answer (score 1):

Create your object like this:

```
var obj = {
a:'a',
b:'b'
};

$.ajax({
    url:"/test",
    type:"POST",
    data:obj,
    success:function(){


    },error:function(){

    }
});
```

Comment: What if there are n objects? obj_1,obj_2...obj_n

Comment: you create a bigger object that has all the objects that you want